# Why can't I access google with http3/quic?

Tags: google-chrome, https, http2, quic, http3

Chrome has turned on the enable-quic switch ,but when i But when I visit google, it still uses http2 protocol ,how can I use the browser's http3/quic feature?

[enable-quic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkeg6.png)
[http2 protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QplEs.png)

Answer (score 7):

Since HTTP/3 is still a relatively new protocol, browser may first use HTTP/1 or HTTP/2 when connecting to a server. The server may advertise support of HTTP/3 for subsequent connections. However, even after several requests, the browser may end up using HTTP/2 and TCP if QUIC handshake is delayed for some reason.

You may find more information here
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/09/http3-practical-deployment-options-part3/

You can try to force Chrome to use QUIC protocol on a specific domain by starting chrome from the command line

```
chrome --origin-to-force-quic-on=www.example.org:443
```